# Custom Coupon Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, dataextensions, microsites

I'm thinking in use LiveContent Coupons in a Site on my server.
The flow would be something like:

- The user with certain UserKey click on a Link on my Site to a Landing
  Page.
- The user Land on the Landing Page of a Microsite of ExactTarget.
- With RequestParameter I read the UserKey.
- With the UserKey I load a Coupon of the Data Extension and assigned it to that UserKey.

With that in mind, I have some questions:

- It is possible to do that?
- If it is possible: There is a way to load the UserKey in "session" for the Coupons to used it?
- Another way could be using ClaimRow to assign the Coupon... but how can I generate the coupon "image" with the coupon number obtained?

Sorry if something isn't clear. Just ask and I can explain it better.
Thanks in advance.